# get all values of ul into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `<ul>` like this:

```
  <ul class="options" id="selt_count">
  <li value="1">One</li>
  <li value="2">Two</li>
  <li value="5">Five</li>
  <li value="12">Other</li>
  </ul>
```

What I want is to get all values of `<li>` into variable in the following format (1,2,5,12) in jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
var values = $('#selt_count li').map(function() {
    return this.value
});
values; // [1, 2, 5, 12]
```

To get a string representation you can do:

```
var s = '(' + values.get().join(',') + ')'; // "(1,2,5,12)"
```

FYI [the value attribute was deprecated a while ago.](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_li_value.asp)

References:

- [jQuery.map](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map)