# Getting the values of a class

Tags: php, arrays, class

I have an html structure similar to this one:

```
<div id="sound_collection">
    <ul class="connected list">
        <li class="highlight" value="1.wav">One</li>
        <li class="highlight" value="2.wav">Two</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to get the values of the class (connected list) into an array. This should then look similar to this one `$files = array("sounds/1.wav", "sounds/2.wav");`.

I basically need this script because the user is able to change the position of the 'li's via a drag and drop script.

Comment: You need to use Ajax to inform php (and the database, probably?) of the changes. You should do that either after each drag/drop operation, or upon th click of. "save" button.

Answer (score 0):

using php, I'm not sure if you can achieve this. you may use `jquery` for it, like this,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var arr = [];
     $('#sound_collection li').each(function(i){    
     arr[i] = "sounds/" + $(this).text();
    });
     alert(arr);
  });​
```

Here's the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWyMz/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here: [get all values of ul into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545167/get-all-values-of-ul-into-variable)

using this:

```
var values = $('#selt_count li').map(function() {
   return this.value
});
values; // [1, 2, 5, 12]
```

And to get string :

```
var s = '(' + values.get().join(',') + ')'; // "(1,2,5,12)"
```